# How to make an app searchable on google search?

Tags: android

I want to search my installed android application on google search. Search will not effect weather the app is live on google play store or not. If application is installed in device, it should be searchable on google.
Can anyone know about this process?

[image]

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/slices/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6041489?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If you published your app on the stores like Google Play, your app will be indexed by the Google search engine. Also, you can read about app indexing in this link:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/

Comment: I want my app to be searched if it is not published on google play store....just it has to be installed on that particular android device...

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta how do you think you can search your application on any search engine if your application is not published anywhere? please rephrase your question.

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta Explore the link you will get familiar with the ways.